# "Full authentication is required to access this resource" Unauthorised - 401 error in spring security example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I enabled Websecurity but i have enabled anyRequest() and permitAll() methods still im getting this error in postman. Below is my code which i have in configuration.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfifguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

            httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .permitAll()
                        .and().httpBasic().disable();

            httpSecurity.csrf().disable();              

    }
}
```

**below is controller code**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/hello")
public class HelloResource {
     @GetMapping
     public String hello() {
         return "Hello World";
     }
}
```

**Application Class**

```
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Error in postman**

```
{
    "timestamp": 1513867805556,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/rest/hello"
}
```

**Recomended But dint help**

```
httpSecurity
      .anonymous() //allow anonymous access
      .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/rest/**").permitAll();
```

im expecting it to return "Hello World" in response.

**2nd Recomendation but didnt help**

```
        httpSecurity
         //some configuration
//            .and()
              .anonymous() //allow anonymous access
              .and()
                 .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config file and resource were not in same package so i was getting the error. now it moved them under main package it started working.[image]

Comment: That was a good point. All the files should in a same package if you want to set up the spring boot security.